# Complicating the logic sentence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I found an interesting assumption on the internet which says: every student of XYZ university has a computer or has a friend who has a computer.

Every textbook took domain x = student of XYZ university

So with that, the answer would be $\forall x (C(x) \lor \exists y (C(y) \land F(x,y)))$

But what if the domain x = all the people in the world, then the sentence would be
$$\forall x (Student(x) \rightarrow (C(x) \lor \exists y (C(y) \land F(x,y)))$$????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, if you change the domain, the logical formulation of the same sentence changes. Your second formulation is indeed correct also for the original domain, it's just that it's a little unneccessary since $Student(x)$ is always true in that case.

Comment: I don't think so, because now the domain is ALL THE PEOPLE ON EARTH, so with Student(x), I am taking only those who are in XYZ. Is that correct?

Comment: @ishwaksharda I do not understand what you are trying to say. You say "I don't think so", but I do not know what this is referring to. Which part of my answer do you disagree with and why?

Comment: Sorry if I could express myself clearly. You said in your answer that Student(x) is unnecessary with the domain of all the people, but if I don't use Student(x), then it doesn't make sense the second one because it would mean that all the people have a computer or have a friend who has a computer.

Comment: @ishwaksharda I did not say that Student(x) is unnecessary with the domain of all the people. I said it is unnecessary in the **original** domain, i.e. the domain of "all students of XYZ".

Comment: Oh....ok that's clearn. Thanks!

Comment: @ishwaksharda If this answer   is what you were looking for, you should accept it